# IMessage not activating and can't select number to receive

Tags: iphone, messages

I got a new SIM card and now I message is not working. Firstly I could only select my e-mail address as the means of being reached and my number is not in bold and can't be ticked. Also when I turn I message activation off and back on again it comes up with an error and just says waiting for activation. Any ideas?

Comment: and who gave you the SIM card ?

Comment: My mobile provider. I was having a coverage issue and they gave me a new sim. However I the issue with the coverage was due to the antenna being lose after my phone was repaired.

Comment: Need more info - iOS version, type of phone, do regular calls/texts work with new SIM, etc.

Comment: Apple servers need time to verify your information, that can be as fast as 1 hour, or up to 24 hours.

Comment: Sorted, it seemed to right itself and iMessage activated after a while. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Apple servers need time to verify your information and to Activate iMessage uses, that can be as [fast as 1 hour](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201422), or up to 24 hours in rare cases.

Some patience is required since it is your privacy apple is working on to protect.

Answer (score 0):

It may just take some time, but if not, Apple recommends that you switch off imessage, restart your iphone and then turn imessage back on. When you switch it back on your phone number should be ticked.
the same goes for Facetime if you have a problem.
https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201422