# Don't see the option to select my mobile number in 'Send & Receive' option of iMessage [iOS 13.3 iPhone 11]

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages, facetime, ios

I recently got a new iPhone 11 and have inserted the sim as part of the setup. Whenever I send text messages to a person, they see my email ID instead of my phone number.

I went to `Settings > iMessage > Send & Receive` but I do not see my phone number there and just see my apple Id. Same for my FaceTime settings. No one is able to FaceTime me using my number and they can do it through only email Id. 
I have also verified my phone number under `Settings > iCloud > Name, Phone Numbers & Email` and I do see my phone number added there.

I checked this [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171816/imessage-not-activating-and-cant-select-number-to-receive) question but as the answer suggests, I have already waited for more than 24 hours. Also checked Apple's support article but still no luck: https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201422

I can see that a good number of people have faced this issue and can see posts across the internet but nothing seems to be working for me. I have also verified that my carrier does let me send and receive SMS.

Comment: have you signout On your iPhone, iPad, and iPod:
Go to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out. && 
Go to Settings > FaceTime. Tap your Apple ID, then tap Sign Out.
And sign in back again with your Apple ID ?

Comment: Tried it just now on iPad and iPhone both still no luck. It’s been saying waiting for activation since then

Comment: If it says waiting for activation, I would suggest waiting for an hour and you can check it again. This generally should help to get rid of your issue.

Comment: ‘Waiting for activation’ is gone now but still don’t see the phone number added under ‘Send & Receive’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for activating iMessage and FaceTime, Apple sends a text message to an international number and my phone plan did not not include international texts. I had to call my cellular service to get international texts activated. iMessage/FaceTime got activated few seconds later.